# Create shell executable Global node module

Tags: node.js, npm

I tried to create node module, I succeeded,
I used `npm install -g` at code directory, and it created this module folder in `\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\myfirstmodule`, Now I want to make one file executable as command, like pm2. How can I do this? so I can type `myfirstmodule` in command prompt at any location and it will execute index.js from that module.

Comment: I don't have an answer but I would look at NPM and the values inside of package.json - as those are the things that called.

Comment: @akaphenom, I tried for that, but I am not getting any key will create a batch file to execute that module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your package.json can provide a map called [bin](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin) which will make commands available. See [this tutorial](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2015/03/node-command-line-tool/) for more details.